# Comment generator for C in C

Tags: c, documentation, executable, generator

I am looking for a (Stand-alone) program that can generate C documentation in C aswell. Take this program as example: 
http://www.feinsoftware.com/CommentMakerPro.php

I would have want to use this, because this is really close to what I would like. Only I don't use visual studio so a stand-alone program, not an add-on would be the best =D

Hope anyone knows a program like this!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: HEW (High-performance Embedded Workspace) for Renesas RX62N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative to tool you already suggested would be:
 - http://www.atomineerutils.com/products.php
 - http://www.wholetomato.com/products/features/documentMethod.asp

Answer (score 2):

Try [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl) works for C (among other languages)

Comment: not exactly what I am looking for.. but thanks for the tip!